# update script doubles counter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-update

I have this small script to update a report counter

```
    /*********************************
     * Report an ad as inappropriate
     * This happens when a user click
     * the "Report ad" link on the ad
     * view page.
     * 
     * The ad can then be reviewed
     * and disabled.
     * 
     * @param int | The ad id
     *********************************/
    function report_ad($aid) {
        $row = $this->db->dbh->query('UPDATE '. $this->config->db_prefix .'_adverts SET been_reported = 1, num_reports = num_reports + 1 WHERE aid = '.$aid.'');
        $row->execute();        
    }
```

and this jQuery to handle the link click

```
$("#report-ad").click(function(){

   var conf = confirm("Do you want to report this ad as inappropriate?");
   var aid = {$smarty.get.aid}

   if(conf == true) {
     $.ajax({
       url: 'reportad.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {literal}{aid: aid}{/literal},
       success: function(data) {
          alert("The ad has been reported as inappropriate");
       },
       error: function(data) {
          alert("An error occured");
       }
     });
  }
  return false;
});
```

reportad.php just contains this:

```
$adverts = new Adverts();
$adverts->report_ad($_POST["aid"]);
```

for some reason it update num_reports with 2, so if it is 1 it will become 3 and then 5 and so on. I cannot see where there problem is.

Comment: Is your Adverts constructor calling the report_ad() method?

Comment: look in browser console....are multiple ajax requests made?

Comment: I have no other requests

Comment: Why not modify your report_ad() method to dump a debug_backtrace to your logs, so that you can see exactly where it's called from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help us helping you: Track down where the error happens:

- What if you execute the Query manually? Also +2? (Stored procedure  incrementing whenever been_reported is set)?
- Is the funktion called multiple times? if you are new to php debugging,

  mail('me@host.com', 'message');

is bad practise but fast to do. (also check file_put_content() for simple non-objectbased logging).

Also, aren't you missing a semicolone after

```
var aid = {$smarty.get.aid}
```

Greets

EDIT: Unsure if query() does a prepared statement, or directly runs the query? In that case query() and execute() would be the double your ale looking for.

Comment: If I execute the query manually it will update it correctly with only +1.

If I do a `curl -X PUT http://www.domain.dk/reportad/43/` via terminal it will update with +2, so it must be something with the script.

Comment: I did not run a prepared statement! I changed it to a prepared statement and voila! It works! Thank you!